# Calculating return based on weekly investment

Tags: r, dplyr

I need help calculating total return based on weekly investments. I'm confused as to how to add subsequent week investment to the running total?

Here is a short example.

```
df = read.csv ( "https://www.dropbox.com/s/11puqepmx2w0vbg/temp25.csv?dl=1")
head ( df, 20 )
```

```
|ref.date  | BTC_close| Total.invested|    bought|     return|
|:---------|---------:|--------------:|---------:|----------:|
|1/1/2022  |  47686.81|            140| 0.0029358|  0.0000000|
|1/2/2022  |  47345.22|              0| 0.0000000| -0.0071632|
|1/3/2022  |  46458.12|              0| 0.0000000| -0.0257658|
|1/4/2022  |  45897.57|              0| 0.0000000| -0.0375206|
|1/5/2022  |  43569.00|              0| 0.0000000| -0.0863511|
|1/6/2022  |  43160.93|              0| 0.0000000| -0.0949084|
|1/7/2022  |  41557.90|              0| 0.0000000| -0.1285242|
|1/8/2022  |  41733.94|            140| 0.0033546| -0.124832632|
|1/9/2022  |  41911.60|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/10/2022 |  41821.26|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/11/2022 |  42735.86|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/12/2022 |  43949.10|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/13/2022 |  42591.57|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/14/2022 |  43099.70|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/15/2022 |  43177.40|            140| 0.0032424|         NA|
|1/16/2022 |  43113.88|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/17/2022 |  42250.55|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/18/2022 |  42375.63|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/19/2022 |  41744.33|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/20/2022 |  40680.42|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/21/2022 |  36457.32|              0| 0.0000000|         NA|
|1/22/2022 |  35030.25|            140| 0.0039965|         NA|
```

So what I want is a running total return for each day based on the total invested. The difficulty is the subsequent weeks, eg 2nd week,  which is composed of returns from the 1st week + the current week and so on.

Is there a way to do this properly? thanks in advance.

Note the date, 1/8/2022 is not just return for that date but return for that date + what ever proceed it. so 0 plus the return from previous.

Comment: Can you add expected output? What about `mutate(df, running_total = replace_na(cumsum(return), 0) + cumsum(Total.invested))`?

Comment: You're going to need to describe what you want to do with respect to specific columns, e.g. defining "total return" mathematically here. As it is now, it's not clear what `Total.invested` actually is showing us and why `return` has a bunch of `NA` values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble knowing what you intend return to mean.  The returns you have shown don't consider the amount of time the investment was made.  I don't think that's really what you want long-term.  I think you'll want annualized return.
So here's some code that does this without the time element, but if you remove the comment, it will calculate an annualized return which includes time.

```
df$value <- df$BTC_close * cumsum(df$bought)
calc_r <- function(i, df) {
  cur_val <- df$value[i]
  ref.date <- as.Date(df$ref.date, '%m/%d/%Y')
  cur_date <- ref.date[1]
  f <- function(r, cv = cur_val, rd = ref.date, cd = cur_date, 
                ti = df$Total.invested){
    accum_val <- sum(ti[1:i] * (1 + r)) # ^ (as.numeric(rd[i] - rd[1:i]) / 365.25))
    cv - accum_val 
  }
uniroot(f, interval = c(-1, 10))$root
}
df$return <- c(0, sapply(2:nrow(df), calc_r, df = df))
```

First I added a column that calculates the current value of all the investments.
If you don't want to consider the time element, you don't need to use uniroot to solve for the return.  r <- curr_val / sum(df$Total.invested[1:i]) would work fine.
But if you eventually want annualized returns, you'll need the uniroot solve.  Just include the commented-out code (removing `) #`).

Which gives:

```
df
    ref.date BTC_close Total.invested      bought       return    value
1   1/1/2022  47686.81            140 0.002935822  0.000000000 140.0000
2   1/2/2022  47345.22              0 0.000000000 -0.007163297 138.9971
3   1/3/2022  46458.12              0 0.000000000 -0.025765923 136.3928
4   1/4/2022  45897.57              0 0.000000000 -0.037520745 134.7471
5   1/5/2022  43569.00              0 0.000000000 -0.086351223 127.9108
6   1/6/2022  43160.93              0 0.000000000 -0.094908515 126.7128
7   1/7/2022  41557.90              0 0.000000000 -0.128524306 122.0066
8   1/8/2022  41733.94            140 0.003354584 -0.062416334 262.5234
9   1/9/2022  41911.60              0 0.000000000 -0.058425071 263.6410
10 1/10/2022  41821.26              0 0.000000000 -0.060454626 263.0727
11 1/11/2022  42735.86              0 0.000000000 -0.039907464 268.8259
12 1/12/2022  43949.10              0 0.000000000 -0.012651135 276.4577
13 1/13/2022  42591.57              0 0.000000000 -0.043149045 267.9183
14 1/14/2022  43099.70              0 0.000000000 -0.031733530 271.1146
15 1/15/2022  43177.40            140 0.003242437 -0.019991963 411.6034
16 1/16/2022  43113.88              0 0.000000000 -0.021433692 410.9978
17 1/17/2022  42250.55              0 0.000000000 -0.041028905 402.7679
18 1/18/2022  42375.63              0 0.000000000 -0.038189934 403.9602
19 1/19/2022  41744.33              0 0.000000000 -0.052518705 397.9421
20 1/20/2022  40680.42              0 0.000000000 -0.076666531 387.8001
21 1/21/2022  36457.32              0 0.000000000 -0.172519267 347.5419
22 1/22/2022  35030.25            140 0.003996546 -0.153682359 473.9379
```